# Erro ao compilar projeto no Visual Basic 6

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Quando tento compilar meu projeto dá esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se é problema com o `Crystal Reports` (Veja ao fundo em azul), ou se é problema mesmo do `Visual Basic` 6. Nunca trabalhei com `VB6`, e minha atuação aqui essa empresa seria apenas com o `Sql Server` 2014, mas para terminar essa tarefa, preciso aumentar o *MaxLength* de um campo no Form, e para isso acontecer, preciso compilar o projeto para validar as alterações. O que salva é meu conhecimento em Delphi, mas fico à deriva quando me apresenta erros de compilação, aí a vaca tosse e tosse muito.

Abri components e chequei tudo referente ao `Crystal Reports`. Apenas um controle eu não consegui checar, que foi esse:`crystal visual linking editor 11.5`. E quando tento agora compilar, me dá a mensagem e já abre a tela de references, conforme imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Instalei a crviewer.dll e agora apareceram mais 4 com status MISSING: Vide imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Selecione o Projeto > References e veja se algumas DLL ou Libraries diz "MISSING." 

Certifique-se também que as 4 Libraries a seguir estão checadas:´
    Visual Basic for Applications
    Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures
    Visual Basic objects and procedures
    OLE Automation´

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, achei isso: `MISSING: Crystal Reports Activex Designer Run Time Library 11.0`. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Você precisa instalar o Crystal Reports nessa maquina.

Comment: Além de verificar o menu de referências, olhe também o menu de componentes. Project -> Components... (Ctrl+T)

Comment: O Crystal está instalado, mas acho que deve estar faltando alguma dll ou ocx, como disse, VB não minha praia.

Comment: clicando em cima do `MISSING: Crystal Reports Activex Designer Run Time Library 11.0` ve qual a DLL que está faltando é a `crviewer.dll`, tenta procurar por ela no seu pc ou na rede.

Comment: @andrepaulo, está cortando e não consigo redimensionar a tela(popup). Vou na sua onda, mas não parece ser isso. Consigo ler até aqui: `...\bin\crax`, depois não consigo ler mais nada. tem outra forma de saber o que ele tá pedindo?

Comment: pesquisando no google msm por esse `MISSING: Crystal Reports Activex Designer Run Time Library 11.0` que da pra chegar nessa dll `crviewer.dll` ai você precisa pegar essa dll, apertar no `brownse` e referenciar ela, se não tiver mais nenhuma referencia faltando vai funcionar. de preferencia tem que pegar a dll da mesma versao, dado que o que foi programado pode ter usado algo especifico da versão referenciada

Comment: Vc instalou a a versão correta do Crystal Reports 11.5?

Comment: Então, a instalação é antiga. Posso ver a versão, mas sempre diz isso: `Crystal reports XI release 2`